# disk full because of tmpdir, safe to restart?

Tags: mariadb

My disk is full, an .MAD file in tmpdir takes up all the space on the file system (179G out of 189G)

from log:

[Warning] mysqld: Disk is full writing '/var/tmp/#sql_b6f_0.MAD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space

Can I stop mariadb, or do I need to free some space first and then stop it?

Comment: I just freed 200 megs on the disk and that space was eaten up in seconds. I have a few gigs left I can free but i need to somehow stop mariadb from eating that space first?

Comment: We just had this. These are Temp files for MariaDB queries. You’ll find many more references to .MYD and .MYI files (what MySQL calls the equivalent). A mariadb/mysqlDB bounce should clear these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do a `service mysqld stop` and that deleted the files in tmpdir, that solved the problem....

Answer (score 1):

Aaargh I had been searching for a fix for exactly 5 hours!
However I'm quite the beginner so yeah... 
We're running our MariaDB on a SUSE Linux server in production, so stopping the whole mysql service was not a good option for me.

I ran a `select` query with nested selects using `order by` and `inner join` and this was my exact error:

> Error Code: 1021 Disk full (/tmp/#sql_*xxx_y*.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device")

By connecting to the server and running

```
cd /tmp
ls -al
```

or

```
ls-lh
```

I could find the culprits: **#sql_*xxx_y*.MAD** (as big as my total available space on tmp partition) and **#sql_*xxx_y*.MAI** size 8K (this must be the temp query). Also the *.MAD file would keep updating its date - yet another indicator of a still running query!

So this thread and [this other one](https://serverfault.com/questions/967402/mariadb-mad-file-take-all-space-in-hard-drive) helped me figure it out:

```
mysql -u root -p
show processlist;
kill "thread_id (number in 1st col of the faulty query)";
```

I ran `show processlist;` twice after that: 1st time it showed my query as *killed*, the 2nd time my query had dissapeared from the list and the ***.MAD*** and **.MAI** files were gone and my disk space back in place.

> Note: luckily my "faulty" query was an ad-hoc select, and did not alter any tables, nor was it set to run on a regular basis/ from some webservice or a client in production. So watch out, if your situation is different then all those threads where someone like me can easily waste 5h might still be useful :D